# Delphi 2007 using Windows Imaging Component (WIC)

Tags: delphi, com, delphi-2007, jpeg, bmp

I need to read and convert some pictures around 1.7mb from jpg to bmp in Delphi 2007.

Some pictures are cut out, grayscale or worst after conversion.

I searched, but in no way i found a trick to add WIC routines like TWicImage in delphi 2007.

I read somewhere that it can be easily added via COM, but I do not know how or what file has to be imported.

Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with the use of built-in JPEG unit ? I'm asking because I'm not sure what you meant with *Some pictures are cut out, grayscale or worst after conversion.* Does it mean that using built-in JPEG unit doesn't handle the images properly ? Do you really need to use WIC ?

Comment: Yes my picture (1.73 MB and 2362 X 1850) does not load properly.
It is loaded all gray, with a piece cut and pasted across the image.
Only got loads it correctly with component TImageEn, however I would like to use something like the native WIC.

Comment: Could you upload a sample image on some file (not image) sharing server, please ? And, I would give a try to Microsoft's GDI+ You can check out the [`difference between GDI and WIC`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/602727/960757). WIC has extended image codec support, but since you're going to convert JPEG to BMP, whose are supported by GDI+ by default, I would prefer GDI+ before WIC.

Comment: http://www.imageurlhost.com/images/vub9oh8z52tyrb1qjpk.jpg

Comment: I can see what you've described, the channels are shifted in a strange way (tested on Delphi 2009), but it's clearly an issue in JPEG library. Just tried GDI+ and it loses color brightness in target bitmap, hmm, strange. GDI+ never failed me. Will try WIC, stay tuned...

Comment: TimageEn loses color and brightness too.

Comment: Right now I finished WIC interface headers, but I have bad news. It behaves the same. It loses a brightness too. Isn't that image saved e.g. in some [`Adobe JPEG`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8920605/960757) format for instance ? I'll re-format the code and post it here also with the GDI+ alternative, but the result will be the same.

Comment: No problem of losing brightness, I already imagined losing a bit of quality in these conversions.

About the image source, I do not know.

I only used it as a reference because i dont know the size and i need to resize to shrink and record in the database. The major problem is in TJpegImage that can't handle high quality images, mainly in delphi 2007.

Comment: Conversion from JPEG to BMP should be loseless, so I'm suspecting either missing codec for that JPEG format or my wrong usage. I'll be right back with code...

Comment: Looks like you have a CMYK jpeg. You might try [enhanced jpeg implementation](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/19723) in code central.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an example how to convert JPEG to bitmap using WIC:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  StdCtrls, Dialogs, ComObj, ActiveX;

const
  WICBitmapCacheOnLoad = $2;
  WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnDemand = 0;

  SID_IPropertyBag2 = '{22F55882-280B-11d0-A8A9-00A0C90C2004}';
  SID_IWICComponentInfo = '{23BC3F0A-698B-4357-886B-F24D50671334}';
  SID_IWICBitmapSource = '{00000120-a8f2-4877-ba0a-fd2b6645fb94}';
  SID_IWICBitmap = '{00000121-a8f2-4877-ba0a-fd2b6645fb94}';
  SID_IWICBitmapLock = '{00000123-a8f2-4877-ba0a-fd2b6645fb94}';
  SID_IWICBitmapCodecInfo = '{E87A44C4-B76E-4c47-8B09-298EB12A2714}';
  SID_IWICBitmapEncoder = '{00000103-a8f2-4877-ba0a-fd2b6645fb94}';
  SID_IWICBitmapDecoder = '{9EDDE9E7-8DEE-47ea-99DF-E6FAF2ED44BF}';
  SID_IWICBitmapEncoderInfo = '{94C9B4EE-A09F-4f92-8A1E-4A9BCE7E76FB}';
  SID_IWICBitmapDecoderInfo = '{D8CD007F-D08F-4191-9BFC-236EA7F0E4B5}';
  SID_IWICBitmapFrameEncode = '{00000105-a8f2-4877-ba0a-fd2b6645fb94}';
  SID_IWICBitmapFrameDecode = '{3B16811B-6A43-4ec9-A813-3D930C13B940}';
  SID_IWICBitmapScaler = '{00000302-a8f2-4877-ba0a-fd2b6645fb94}';
  SID_IWICBitmapClipper = '{E4FBCF03-223D-4e81-9333-D635556DD1B5}';
  SID_IWICBitmapFlipRotator = '{5009834F-2D6A-41ce-9E1B-17C5AFF7A782}';
  SID_IWICPalette = '{00000040-a8f2-4877-ba0a-fd2b6645fb94}';
  SID_IWICColorContext = '{3C613A02-34B2-44ea-9A7C-45AEA9C6FD6D}';
  SID_IWICColorTransform = '{B66F034F-D0E2-40ab-B436-6DE39E321A94}';
  SID_IWICMetadataQueryReader = '{30989668-E1C9-4597-B395-458EEDB808DF}';
  SID_IWICMetadataQueryWriter = '{A721791A-0DEF-4d06-BD91-2118BF1DB10B}';
  SID_IWICFastMetadataEncoder = '{B84E2C09-78C9-4AC4-8BD3-524AE1663A2F}';
  SID_IWICStream = '{135FF860-22B7-4ddf-B0F6-218F4F299A43}';
  SID_IWICFormatConverter = '{00000301-a8f2-4877-ba0a-fd2b6645fb94}';
  SID_IWICImagingFactory = '{ec5ec8a9-c395-4314-9c77-54d7a935ff70}';
  CLSID_WICImagingFactory: TGUID = '{CACAF262-9370-4615-A13B-9F5539DA4C0A}';
  GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppBGRA: TGUID = '{6FDDC324-4E03-4BFE-B185-3D77768DC90F}';

type
  PWICColor = ^TWicColor;
  TWICColor = Cardinal;
  PWICRect = ^TWICRect;
  TWICRect = record
    X: Integer;
    Y: Integer;
    Width: Integer;
    Height: Integer;
  end;
  PIWICColorContext = ^IWICColorContext;
  PWICBitmapPattern = ^TWICBitmapPattern;
  TWICBitmapPattern = record
    Position: ULARGE_INTEGER;
    Length: ULONG;
    Pattern: PByte;
    Mask: PByte;
    EndOfStream: BOOL;
  end;
  PPropBag2 = ^TPropBag2;
  TPropBag2 = record
    dwType: DWORD;
    vt: TVarType;
    cfType: TClipFormat;
    dwHint: DWORD;
    pstrName: POleStr;
    clsid: TCLSID;
  end;
  TWICInProcPointer = ^Byte;
  TWICPixelFormatGUID = TGUID;
  TREFWICPixelFormatGUID = PGUID;
  TWICComponentType = type Integer;
  TWICDecodeOptions = type Integer;
  TWICColorContextType = type Integer;
  TWICBitmapDitherType = type Integer;
  TWICBitmapPaletteType = type Integer;
  TWICBitmapInterpolationMode = type Integer;
  TWICBitmapEncoderCacheOption = type Integer;
  TWICBitmapTransformOptions = type Integer;
  TWICBitmapCreateCacheOption = type Integer;
  TWICBitmapAlphaChannelOption = type Integer;

  IPropertyBag2 = interface;
  IWICPalette = interface;
  IWICColorContext = interface;
  IWICColorTransform = interface;
  IWICBitmap = interface;
  IWICBitmapLock = interface;
  IWICBitmapSource = interface;
  IWICBitmapCodecInfo = interface;
  IWICBitmapEncoder = interface;
  IWICBitmapDecoder = interface;
  IWICBitmapEncoderInfo = interface;
  IWICBitmapDecoderInfo = interface;
  IWICBitmapFrameEncode = interface;
  IWICBitmapFrameDecode = interface;
  IWICBitmapScaler = interface;
  IWICBitmapClipper = interface;
  IWICBitmapFlipRotator = interface;
  IWICMetadataQueryReader = interface;
  IWICMetadataQueryWriter = interface;
  IWICFastMetadataEncoder = interface;
  IWICStream = interface;
  IWICComponentInfo = interface;
  IWICFormatConverter = interface;
  IWICImagingFactory = interface;

  IPropertyBag2 = interface(IUnknown)
    [SID_IPropertyBag2]
    function Read(pPropBag: PPropBag2; pErrLog: IErrorLog; pvarValue: PVariant; phrError: PHResult): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function Write(cProperties: ULONG; pPropBag: PPropBag2; pvarValue: PVariant): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CountProperties(var pcProperties: ULONG): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetPropertyInfo(iProperty, cProperties: ULONG; pPropBag: PPropBag2; var pcProperties: ULONG): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function LoadObject(pstrName:POleStr; dwHint: DWORD; pUnkObject: IUnknown; pErrLog: IErrorLog): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICComponentInfo = interface(IUnknown)
    [SID_IWICComponentInfo]
    function GetComponentType(var pType: TWICComponentType): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetCLSID(var pclsid: TGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetSigningStatus(var pStatus: DWORD): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetAuthor(cchAuthor: UINT; wzAuthor: PWCHAR; var pcchActual: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetVendorGUID(var pguidVendor: TGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetVersion(cchVersion: UINT; wzVersion: PWCHAR; var pcchActual: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetSpecVersion(cchSpecVersion: UINT; wzSpecVersion: PWCHAR; var pcchActual: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetFriendlyName(cchFriendlyName: UINT; wzFriendlyName: PWCHAR; var pcchActual: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICBitmapSource = interface(IUnknown)
    [SID_IWICBitmapSource]
    function GetSize(var puiWidth: UINT; var puiHeight: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetPixelFormat(var pPixelFormat: TWICPixelFormatGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetResolution(var pDpiX: Double; var pDpiY: Double): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CopyPalette(pIPalette: IWICPalette): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CopyPixels(prc: PWICRect; cbStride: UINT; cbBufferSize: UINT; pbBuffer: PByte): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICBitmap = interface(IWICBitmapSource)
    [SID_IWICBitmap]
    function Lock(const prcLock: TWICRect; flags: DWORD; out ppILock: IWICBitmapLock): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetPalette(pIPalette: IWICPalette): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetResolution(dpiX: Double; dpiY: Double): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICBitmapLock = interface(IUnknown)
    [SID_IWICBitmapLock]
    function GetSize(var puiWidth: UINT; var puiHeight: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetStride(var pcbStride: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetDataPointer(var pcbBufferSize: UINT; var ppbData: TWICInProcPointer): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetPixelFormat(var pPixelFormat: TWICPixelFormatGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICBitmapCodecInfo = interface(IWICComponentInfo)
    [SID_IWICBitmapCodecInfo]
    function GetContainerFormat(var pguidContainerFormat: TGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetPixelFormats(cFormats: UINT; var guidPixelFormats: PGUID; var pcActual: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetColorManagementVersion(cchColorManagementVersion: UINT; wzColorManagementVersion: PWCHAR; var pcchActual: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetDeviceManufacturer(cchDeviceManufacturer: UINT; wzDeviceManufacturer: PWCHAR; var pcchActual: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetDeviceModels(cchDeviceModels: UINT; wzDeviceModels: PWCHAR; var pcchActual: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetMimeTypes(cchMimeTypes: UINT; wzMimeTypes: PWCHAR; var pcchActual: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetFileExtensions(cchFileExtensions: UINT; wzFileExtensions: PWCHAR; var pcchActual: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function DoesSupportAnimation(var pfSupportAnimation: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function DoesSupportChromakey(var pfSupportChromakey: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function DoesSupportLossless(var pfSupportLossless: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function DoesSupportMultiframe(var pfSupportMultiframe: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function MatchesMimeType(wzMimeType: LPCWSTR; var pfMatches: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICBitmapEncoder = interface(IUnknown)
    [SID_IWICBitmapEncoder]
    function Initialize(pIStream: IStream; cacheOption: TWICBitmapEncoderCacheOption): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetContainerFormat(var pguidContainerFormat: TGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetEncoderInfo(out ppIEncoderInfo: IWICBitmapEncoderInfo): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetColorContexts(cCount: UINT; ppIColorContext: PIWICColorContext): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetPalette(pIPalette: IWICPalette): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetThumbnail(pIThumbnail: IWICBitmapSource): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetPreview(pIPreview: IWICBitmapSource): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateNewFrame(out ppIFrameEncode: IWICBitmapFrameEncode; var ppIEncoderOptions: IPropertyBag2): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function Commit: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetMetadataQueryWriter(out ppIMetadataQueryWriter: IWICMetadataQueryWriter): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICBitmapDecoder = interface(IUnknown)
    [SID_IWICBitmapDecoder]
    function QueryCapability(pIStream: IStream; var pdwCapability: DWORD): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function Initialize(pIStream: IStream; cacheOptions: TWICDecodeOptions): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetContainerFormat(var pguidContainerFormat: TGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetDecoderInfo(out ppIDecoderInfo: IWICBitmapDecoderInfo): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CopyPalette(pIPalette: IWICPalette): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetMetadataQueryReader(out ppIMetadataQueryReader: IWICMetadataQueryReader): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetPreview(out ppIBitmapSource: IWICBitmapSource): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetColorContexts(cCount: UINT; ppIColorContexts: PIWICColorContext; var pcActualCount : UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetThumbnail(out ppIThumbnail: IWICBitmapSource): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetFrameCount(var pCount: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetFrame(index: UINT; out ppIBitmapFrame: IWICBitmapFrameDecode): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICBitmapEncoderInfo = interface(IWICBitmapCodecInfo)
    [SID_IWICBitmapEncoderInfo]
    function CreateInstance(out ppIBitmapEncoder: IWICBitmapEncoder): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICBitmapDecoderInfo = interface(IWICBitmapCodecInfo)
    [SID_IWICBitmapDecoderInfo]
    function GetPatterns(cbSizePatterns: UINT; pPatterns: PWICBitmapPattern; var pcPatterns: UINT; var pcbPatternsActual: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function MatchesPattern(pIStream: IStream; var pfMatches: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateInstance(out ppIBitmapDecoder: IWICBitmapDecoder): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICBitmapFrameEncode = interface(IUnknown)
    [SID_IWICBitmapFrameEncode]
    function Initialize(pIEncoderOptions: IPropertyBag2): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetSize(uiWidth: UINT; uiHeight: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetResolution(dpiX: Double; dpiY: Double): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetPixelFormat(var pPixelFormat: TWICPixelFormatGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetColorContexts(cCount: UINT; ppIColorContext: PIWICColorContext): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetPalette(pIPalette: IWICPalette): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function SetThumbnail(pIThumbnail: IWICBitmapSource): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function WritePixels(lineCount: UINT; cbStride: UINT; cbBufferSize: UINT; pbPixels: PByte): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function WriteSource(pIBitmapSource: IWICBitmapSource; prc: PWICRect): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function Commit: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetMetadataQueryWriter(out ppIMetadataQueryWriter: IWICMetadataQueryWriter): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICBitmapFrameDecode = interface(IWICBitmapSource)
    [SID_IWICBitmapFrameDecode]
    function GetMetadataQueryReader(out ppIMetadataQueryReader: IWICMetadataQueryReader): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetColorContexts(cCount: UINT; ppIColorContexts: PIWICColorContext; var pcActualCount : UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetThumbnail(out ppIThumbnail: IWICBitmapSource): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICBitmapScaler = interface(IWICBitmapSource)
    [SID_IWICBitmapScaler]
    function Initialize(pISource: IWICBitmapSource; uiWidth: UINT; uiHeight: UINT; mode: TWICBitmapInterpolationMode): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICBitmapClipper = interface(IWICBitmapSource)
    [SID_IWICBitmapClipper]
    function Initialize(pISource: IWICBitmapSource; var prc: TWICRect): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICBitmapFlipRotator = interface(IWICBitmapSource)
    [SID_IWICBitmapFlipRotator]
    function Initialize(pISource: IWICBitmapSource; options: TWICBitmapTransformOptions): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICPalette = interface(IUnknown)
    [SID_IWICPalette]
    function InitializePredefined(ePaletteType: TWICBitmapPaletteType; fAddTransparentColor: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function InitializeCustom(pColors: PWICColor; cCount: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function InitializeFromBitmap(pISurface: IWICBitmapSource; cCount: UINT; fAddTransparentColor: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function InitializeFromPalette(pIPalette: IWICPalette): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetType(var pePaletteType: TWICBitmapPaletteType): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetColorCount(var pcCount: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetColors(cCount: UINT; pColors: PWICColor; var pcActualColors: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function IsBlackWhite(var pfIsBlackWhite: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function IsGrayscale(var pfIsGrayscale: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function HasAlpha(var pfHasAlpha: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICColorContext = interface(IUnknown)
    [SID_IWICColorContext]
    function InitializeFromFilename(wzFilename: LPCWSTR): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function InitializeFromMemory(const pbBuffer: PByte; cbBufferSize: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function InitializeFromExifColorSpace(value: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetType(var pType: TWICColorContextType): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetProfileBytes(cbBuffer: UINT; pbBuffer: PByte; var pcbActual: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetExifColorSpace(var pValue: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICColorTransform = interface(IWICBitmapSource)
    [SID_IWICColorTransform]
    function Initialize(pIBitmapSource: IWICBitmapSource; pIContextSource: IWICColorContext; pIContextDest: IWICColorContext; pixelFmtDest: TREFWICPixelFormatGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICMetadataQueryReader = interface(IUnknown)
    [SID_IWICMetadataQueryReader]
    function GetContainerFormat(var pguidContainerFormat: TGUID): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetLocation(cchMaxLength: UINT; wzNamespace: PWCHAR; var pcchActualLength: UINT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetMetadataByName(wzName: LPCWSTR; var pvarValue: PROPVARIANT): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetEnumerator(out ppIEnumString: IEnumString): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICMetadataQueryWriter = interface(IWICMetadataQueryReader)
    [SID_IWICMetadataQueryWriter]
    function SetMetadataByName(wzName: LPCWSTR; const pvarValue: TPropVariant): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function RemoveMetadataByName(wzName: LPCWSTR): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICFastMetadataEncoder = interface(IUnknown)
    [SID_IWICFastMetadataEncoder]
    function Commit: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetMetadataQueryWriter(out ppIMetadataQueryWriter: IWICMetadataQueryWriter): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICStream = interface(IStream)
    [SID_IWICStream]
    function InitializeFromIStream(pIStream: IStream): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function InitializeFromFilename(wzFileName: LPCWSTR; dwDesiredAccess: DWORD): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function InitializeFromMemory(pbBuffer: TWICInProcPointer; cbBufferSize: DWORD): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function InitializeFromIStreamRegion(pIStream: IStream; ulOffset: ULARGE_INTEGER; ulMaxSize: ULARGE_INTEGER): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICFormatConverter = interface(IWICBitmapSource)
    [SID_IWICFormatConverter]
    function Initialize(pISource: IWICBitmapSource; const dstFormat: TWICPixelFormatGUID; dither: TWICBitmapDitherType; const pIPalette: IWICPalette; alphaThresholdPercent: Double; paletteTranslate: TWICBitmapPaletteType): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CanConvert(srcPixelFormat: TREFWICPixelFormatGUID; dstPixelFormat: TREFWICPixelFormatGUID; var pfCanConvert: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;
  IWICImagingFactory = interface(IUnknown)
    [SID_IWICImagingFactory]
    function CreateDecoderFromFilename(wzFilename: LPCWSTR; const pguidVendor: TGUID; dwDesiredAccess: DWORD; metadataOptions: TWICDecodeOptions; out ppIDecoder: IWICBitmapDecoder): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateDecoderFromStream(pIStream: IStream; const pguidVendor: TGUID; metadataOptions: TWICDecodeOptions; out ppIDecoder: IWICBitmapDecoder): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateDecoderFromFileHandle(hFile: ULONG_PTR; const pguidVendor: TGUID; metadataOptions: TWICDecodeOptions; out ppIDecoder: IWICBitmapDecoder): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateComponentInfo(const clsidComponent: TGUID; out ppIInfo: IWICComponentInfo): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateDecoder(const guidContainerFormat: TGUID; const pguidVendor: TGUID; out ppIDecoder: IWICBitmapDecoder): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateEncoder(const guidContainerFormat: TGUID; const pguidVendor: TGUID; out ppIEncoder: IWICBitmapEncoder): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreatePalette(out ppIPalette: IWICPalette): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateFormatConverter(out ppIFormatConverter: IWICFormatConverter): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateBitmapScaler(out ppIBitmapScaler: IWICBitmapScaler): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateBitmapClipper(out ppIBitmapClipper: IWICBitmapClipper): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateBitmapFlipRotator(out ppIBitmapFlipRotator: IWICBitmapFlipRotator): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateStream(out ppIWICStream: IWICStream): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateColorContext(out ppIWICColorContext: IWICColorContext): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateColorTransformer(out ppIWICColorTransform: IWICColorTransform): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateBitmap(uiWidth: UINT; uiHeight: UINT; pixelFormat: TREFWICPixelFormatGUID; option: TWICBitmapCreateCacheOption; out ppIBitmap: IWICBitmap): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateBitmapFromSource(pIBitmapSource: IWICBitmapSource; option: TWICBitmapCreateCacheOption; out ppIBitmap: IWICBitmap): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateBitmapFromSourceRect(pIBitmapSource: IWICBitmapSource; x: UINT; y: UINT; width: UINT; height: UINT; out ppIBitmap: IWICBitmap): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateBitmapFromMemory(uiWidth: UINT; uiHeight: UINT; const pixelFormat: TWICPixelFormatGUID; cbStride: UINT; cbBufferSize: UINT; pbBuffer: PByte; out ppIBitmap: IWICBitmap): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateBitmapFromHBITMAP(hBitmap: HBITMAP; hPalette: HPALETTE; options: TWICBitmapAlphaChannelOption; out ppIBitmap: IWICBitmap): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateBitmapFromHICON(hIcon: HICON; out ppIBitmap: IWICBitmap): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateComponentEnumerator(componentTypes: DWORD; options: DWORD; out ppIEnumUnknown: IEnumUnknown): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateFastMetadataEncoderFromDecoder(pIDecoder: IWICBitmapDecoder; out ppIFastEncoder: IWICFastMetadataEncoder): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateFastMetadataEncoderFromFrameDecode(pIFrameDecoder: IWICBitmapFrameDecode; out ppIFastEncoder: IWICFastMetadataEncoder): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateQueryWriter(const guidMetadataFormat: TGUID; const pguidVendor: TGUID; out ppIQueryWriter: IWICMetadataQueryWriter): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function CreateQueryWriterFromReader(pIQueryReader: IWICMetadataQueryReader; const pguidVendor: TGUID; out ppIQueryWriter: IWICMetadataQueryWriter): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

  function WICConvertBitmapSource(const dstFormat: TWICPixelFormatGUID; pISrc: IWICBitmapSource; out ppIDst: IWICBitmapSource): HRESULT; stdcall;
    external 'windowscodecs.dll' name 'WICConvertBitmapSource';

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FImagingFactory: IWICImagingFactory;
    procedure JpegToBitmap(const ASource, ATarget: string);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.JpegToBitmap(const ASource, ATarget: string);
var
  FileStream: TFileStream;
  StreamAdapter: TStreamAdapter;
  BitmapInfo: TBitmapInfo;
  BitmapBits: array of Byte;
  BitmapWidth: Cardinal;
  BitmapHeight: Cardinal;
  BitmapOutput: TBitmap;
  BitmapObject: IWICBitmap;
  BitmapSource: IWICBitmapSource;
  BitmapDecoder: IWICBitmapDecoder;
  BitmapFrame: IWICBitmapFrameDecode;
begin
  if not Assigned(FImagingFactory) then
    CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER or
      CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IUnknown, FImagingFactory);

  FileStream := TFileStream.Create(ASource, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    FileStream.Position := 0;
    StreamAdapter := TStreamAdapter.Create(FileStream);

    OleCheck(FImagingFactory.CreateDecoderFromStream(StreamAdapter, GUID_NULL,
      WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnDemand, BitmapDecoder));
    OleCheck(BitmapDecoder.GetFrame(0, BitmapFrame));
    OleCheck(FImagingFactory.CreateBitmapFromSource(BitmapFrame,
      WICBitmapCacheOnLoad, BitmapObject));
    OleCheck(BitmapObject.GetSize(BitmapWidth, BitmapHeight));
    SetLength(BitmapBits, BitmapWidth * BitmapHeight * 4);
    OleCheck(WICConvertBitmapSource(GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppBGRA, BitmapObject,
      BitmapSource));
    OleCheck(BitmapSource.CopyPixels(nil, BitmapWidth * 4, Length(BitmapBits),
      @BitmapBits[0]));

    FillChar(BitmapInfo, SizeOf(BitmapInfo), 0);
    BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biSize := SizeOf(BitmapInfo);
    BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth := BitmapWidth;
    BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight := -BitmapHeight;
    BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes := 1;
    BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount := 32;

    BitmapOutput := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      BitmapOutput.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
      BitmapOutput.SetSize(BitmapWidth, BitmapHeight);
      SetDIBits(0, BitmapOutput.Handle, 0, BitmapHeight, @BitmapBits[0],
        BitmapInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
      BitmapOutput.AlphaFormat := afDefined;
      BitmapOutput.SaveToFile(ATarget);
    finally
      BitmapOutput.Free;
    end;
  finally
    FileStream.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  JpegToBitmap('d:\SourceImage.jpg', 'd:\TargetImage.bmp');
end;

end.
```

Comment: Using GDI+ results to the same and it's code on 2 lines, but I can't find a [`wrapper for Delphi 2007`](http://www.bilsen.com/gdiplus/index.shtml)...

Comment: May i ask you how do you import / or found a way to load this code? By the way, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome! You cannot import this type of library. You have to translate it manually from header files available in Windows SDK.

Comment: @TLama - Thanks for posting this library!!! Would you be kind to summarize the pros and cons of WIC (vs native Delphi jpeg lib)? The obvious ones are that Wic is platform dependent but if handles better 'strange' jpeg files. What about speed? Thanks!